# String date convertion to Date Conversion

Tags: java, date-formatting, java.util.date

My requirement is to convert the string ***"2019-04-25 07:06:42.790"*** to `Date` Object with same format as ***"2019-04-25 07:06:42.790"***.

I tried to do this, but it is always giving in String format.

```
    String createDate = "2019-04-25 07:06:42.790";

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.US);
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(createDate, formatter);

    System.out.println(formatter.format(localDateTime));

    SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.US);
    formatter1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));

    Date date = formatter1.parse(createDate);
    System.out.println(date);
    
    String formattedDateString = formatter1.format(date);
    System.out.println(formattedDateString);
```

Output from the above code:

```
2019-04-25 07:06:42.790
Thu Apr 25 07:06:42 IST 2019
2019-04-25 07:06:42.790
```

Comment: This should help https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: See also: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: You are asking the impossible. A `Date` cannot have a format (neither can a `LocalDateTime`). You can have any format you like, but only in a `String`.

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

Date-time objects do not have a “format”.

Use only *java.time* classes.

```
LocalDateTime
.parse ( 
    "2019-04-25 07:06:42.790"
    .replace( " " , "T" ) 
)
.toString()
.replace( "T" , " " )
```

## Details

You need to understand that date-time objects are not text. They don’t have a “format”. The do parse and generate text in various formats, but that text is always external.

Use only the *java.time* classes. Avoid legacy classes such as `Date` and `Calendar`.

Make your input comply with ISO 8601 standard.

```
String input = "2019-04-25 07:06:42.790".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
```

Parse as a `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse ( input ) ;
```

To generate the same text as your input, call `toString` and replace the `T` with your desired SPACE character.

You could use a `DateTimeFormatter` rather than the string manipulations shown above. But in your specific case I recommend the string manipulations.

Comment: So if want this 2019-04-25 07:06:42.790 String in Date datatype its not possible is that so?

Comment: @Vikas: You can represent *the data itself* but not the text format. Just format the appropriate type (e.g. `LocalDateTime`) in whatever format you want later on.

Comment: @Basil So this i tried 
         String input = "2019-04-25 07:06:42.790".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
  LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse ( input ) ;
  
  Date in = new Date();
  ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(in.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
  Date out = Date.from(ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
  System.out.println(ldt+ " OUT "+ out) ;

But the ouput is - 2022-04-08T11:28:22.810 OUT Fri Apr 08 11:28:22 IST 2022
This is not i want to achieve.

Comment: @Vikas I already advised you to stop using the terrible legacy classes. The *java.time* classes completely replace them.